# Cannot add a WCF Data Service reference

Tags: wcf-data-services

I can use a browser to navigate via 'http://localhost:57695/AgentDataService.svc, but when I try to add a Service Reference to a console application within my solution, I get the error message:

There was an error downloading 'http://localhost:57695/AgentDataService.svc/_vti_bin/ListData.svc/$metadata'.
The request failed with HTTP status 404: Not Found.
Metadata contains a reference that cannot be resolved:

I don't know what can be causing this.

Comment: Wild guess, but could you try changing your console app from .Net Client Profile to the full .Net Framework, and see what happens?

Comment: Also, if you can post the output of the $metadata, I can take a look and see why its failing.